# Excel Retrieving Data from website through Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I took a look at [Speed up processing between VBA and IE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45635/speed-up-processing-between-vba-and-ie), but I didn't see anything that addressed the speeding up of the retrieval of information via IE.

Since MS got rid of the stock retrieval database (MSN Money), there wasn't an [easy way to get current stock prices](https://superuser.com/q/745160/116196). From what I gather, there are some [add-ins](https://superuser.com/a/1047419/116196) available through the app store, but like usual, *I'm stuck on 2007* doing this.

This was my attempt at a UDF for retrieving the stock price from `http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/` which requires finding elements on the page and getting the value from within. It's.. not very elegant, but it works. What can I do to speed up the IE processes? I know, I know - screenupdating, etc

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetTickerPrice(ByVal ticker As String) As Double

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim pageData As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/fi-126.1." & ticker & ".NAS?symbol=" & ticker & "=PRFIMQ"

    IE.Navigate URL

     Do Until IE.ReadyState >= 4
            DoEvents
     Loop

     Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

     Set pageData = IE.document

     GetTickerPrice = pageData.getElementsByClassName("precurrentvalue")(0).innertext

     Set IE = Nothing
     Set pageData = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe [using an API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1149922/3207406) is cleaner? The speed issue is very likely because of the time needed to open the URL: instead you could just fetch the HTML page (without displaying it in IT) and search the price. If it is not fast enough, you might need to perform concurrent http requests (for the different stock prices)

Comment: @oliverpool maybe, when I was messing around with the API, I wasn't sure if I could do anything with the csv without downloading and opening it, which may or may not be faster.

Comment: I think this is one of the rare cases when your question would be better asked on SO. Namely, something like "Fastest way to load and retrieve element values from a webpage using VBA"

Comment: Why are you using VBA at all... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708F2249-9569-4FF9-A8A4-7EE5F1B1CFBA  (let alone automating IE)

Comment: @JamesSnell I *thought* that the msn money connections were deprecated in 2013.

Comment: The service might well have been, but you could always modify it or create your own IQY file - there are plenty of web services around that you can use.

Comment: @JamesSnell Jusr curious, do you have any evidence for speed of webqueries vs the approach presented here? My experience with webqueries is that they can still be pretty slow.

Comment: @Zak - Not off the top of my head but my experience says it'll be a good deal quicker than launching a separate process...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worksheet functions were not designed for this. User-defined worksheet functions were not made a feature of Excel to go and fetch data online - in my humble opinion, this is a terrible abuse of UDF's.

A function like this should be part of the definition of a class module that defines an object responsible for this task, and wrapped with an interface, say `ITickerPriceProvider`:

```
Public Function GetTickerPrice(ByVal ticker As String) As Double
End Function
```

Then your code moves into a class module with `Implements ITickerPriceProvider`, and the signature becomes this:

```
Option Explicit
Implements ITickerPriceProvider

Private Function ITickerPriceProvider_GetTickerPrice(ByVal ticker As String) As Double
    'your code
End Function
```

What gives? Now you can get fancy and write a macro that looks like this:

```
Public Sub UpdateTickerPrices()

    Dim provider As ITickerPriceProvider
    Set provider = New WebTickerPriceProvider

    Dim updater As TickerSheetUpdater
    Set updater = New TickerSheetUpdater

    updater.UpdateTickerPrices provider, TickerPricesSheet

End Sub
```

And the `TickerSheetUpdater.UpdateTickerPrices` method is where you go and implement the code that locates ticker strings (your worksheet must have a column with those, right?), fetches the prices for each one, and updates the worksheet.

This is a job for a macro, not a UDF.

As a bonus, the `TickerSheetUpdater` class can be unit-tested because the dependencies are under control - and now if somebody cuts the network cable, you can handle errors gracefully, instead of having 200 UDF calls blowing up one after another.

---

As for the implementation itself, I don't see any glaring issues. I would have named `IE` something like `browser`, `URL` would have been `url`, and there would have been an `On Error GoTo CleanFail` statement at the top, and a `CleanExit` label to ensure resources get cleaned up whether or not an error occurs:

```
Private Function ITickerPriceProvider_GetTickerPrice(ByVal ticker As String) As Double
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'implementation here

CleanExit:
    Set browser = Nothing
    Set pageData = Nothing
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    'handle errors
    Resume CleanExit

End Function
```

Turning `ScreenUpdating` off isn't going to help much, at least not with a UDF approach - the function isn't updating any cell values, it *is* a cell value.

However I'd try to see if there wouldn't be a way to remove this:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
```

...or add a comment that explains *why* it's needed, and *why* it needs to be a whole 5 seconds - especially given you've just waited for a specific `ReadyState` on your `IE` object:

```
 Do Until IE.ReadyState >= 4
        DoEvents
 Loop
```

What's `4` anyway? Make an `Enum` for the possible values, and use it instead of hard-coding a value like this. Why do you need to wait 5 seconds *after* the browser gets into that `ReadyState`? Could you keep loop-waiting for a later state value? An enum would help understanding what's going on and why here.

Comment: @Raystafarian notice it leaves you the freedom to implement some `XmlTickerPriceProvider` and/or `CsvTickerPriceProvider` and/or `SqlTickerPriceProvider`, or whatever other way you might want to fetch this data =)

Comment: It's a better solution than mine, for sure. You might want to post it over at the [superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/745160/how-do-i-download-a-stock-price-in-excel-2013-is-there-an-equivalent-to-google) I was attempting to solve for the bounty.